# Recursive function to find all subgroups

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I'm having trouble creating a recursive function in JavaScript.
I have an array with groups, where each group has an unique ID, a name and a "parent" (references to an ID of a group).

The point of my recursive function would be to list all subgroups starting from one point. It's like an organizational chart, where as you start from the top and list every subgroups with their children.

The array *groups* consists of the following data:

```
var groups = [{ id: 1, naam: "Directie", parent: 1 },
              { id: 2, naam: "Marketing", parent: 1 },
              { id: 3, naam: "Human Resources", parent: 1 },
              { id: 4, naam: "Financieel", parent: 2 },
              { id: 5, naam: "Verkoop", parent: 3 }];
```

The following code is only usable for finding the immediate children, but it's not searching deeper into the next levels.

```
var group = $("#groepen :selected").val();

var output = "";
var hasChildren = false;
var children = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++)
{
    if(groups[i].parent === parseInt(group))
    {
        children++;
        output += "Group ID: " + groups[i].id + "\nGroup name: " + groups[i].naam + 
             "\nGroup parent: " + groups[i].parent + 
             "\n---------------------------------------------\n";
        hasChildren = true;
    }
}

output = "Children: " + children + 
   "\n---------------------------------------------\n" + output;

if(!hasChildren)
{
    output = "No data found";   
}

$("#groups").html(output);
```

So in the following situation where the variable *group* would be "Directie", I would get the following results:
- Directie (root)
- Marketing
- Human Resources

But it's not going deeper into the next levels. 
The result I want is this:
- Directie (root)
- Marketing
- Financieel
- Human Resources
- Verkoop

The order itself doesn't really matter, I just want to list up all groups that are subgroups of "Directie".

*NOTE: I also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/obsseyht/) with the current code. To test this out, just click the "search" button and select a "root" group from the dropdownlist.*

Comment: by "group" you mean a list of nodes and leaves by knowing the root of the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your for your function to be recursive it needs to call itself. Since your looking for parent child relations you'll have to start with the parent and then use a function to find each child. Inside your loop call your function again but pass the current child into the function to find that item's children. I'm not sure exactly how you want to data to be output but this function gets the order you described in your question.

```
var groups = [{
    id: 1,
    naam: "Directie",
    parent: 0
}, {
    id: 2,
    naam: "Marketing",
    parent: 1
}, {
    id: 3,
    naam: "Human Resources",
    parent: 1
}, {
    id: 4,
    naam: "Financieel",
    parent: 2
}, {
    id: 5,
    naam: "Verkoop",
    parent: 3
}];

function getChildren( parent ) {

    for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {

        if (groups[i].parent === parent.id ) {
            var output = "Group ID: " + groups[i].id + "\nGroup name: " + groups[i].naam + "\nGroup parent: " + groups[i].parent + "\n---------------------------------------------\n";

            $('textarea').append( output );
            getChildren( groups[i] );
        }
    }
}

getChildren( groups[0] )
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1199fy7/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recursive function to extract all children in deepest possible nodes and leaves. This function would do what you want:

```js
function getSubTree(tree, root) {
    var i, j, nextNodes, subtree = [], currentNodes = [root];
    while (currentNodes.length > 0) {
        subtree = subtree.concat(currentNodes);
        nextNodes = [];
        for (i=0; i < currentNodes.length; i++) {
            for (j=0; j < tree.length; j++) {
                if (tree[j].parent == currentNodes[i].id) {
                    if (currentNodes[i].id == tree[j].id) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    nextNodes.push(tree[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        currentNodes = nextNodes;
    }
    return subtree;
}
```

In your case, you can run it like this:

```
var subTree = getSubTree(groups, {
    id: 1,
    naam: "Directie",
    parent: 1
});
```

The `tree` or as you called in `group` have to be an array of objects with `id` and `parent` (same as your data structure here).

The algorithm in one sentence: Try to add nodes from `tree` to `subtree`, until you couldn't find any node related to subtree.